# Which of these sums gives the number of operations executed by the above algorithm?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

Question:

Consider the following code:

```
def f(n):
    total = 0 
    i=1
    while i <= n:
       for j in range(i):
           total = total + 1
       i=i*2 
    return total
```

Which of these sums gives the number of operations executed by the above algorithm? Assume that n is a power of 2.

A. $ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i1$

B. $ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{\log_2(n)}1$

C. $ \sum_{i=1}^{\log_2(n)} \sum_{j=1}^i1$

D. $ \sum_{i=1}^{\log_2(n)} \sum_{j=1}^{\log_2(n)}1$

My guess is C but I am not sure why. Could someone please explain how to come up with a sum for the number of steps taken by a iterative algorithm? How do we setup a sum like this when we are given a function with loops?

Comment: None of the sums seem to be including the `i=i*2` step, or the two `total =0` and `i=1` operations. Also, the loops themselves take operations to run, don't they? Can you be a bit more specific about what you mean by "operation"? Is it the final value of `total` you are actually asked about?

Comment: I think the question means number of steps

Comment: That doesn't help much, as I don't know what a step is. Is a step the execution of a line? In that case the problems in my previous comment are still there. I still think that the problem is really after the return value of `total`, in other words, how many times the `total = total + 1` line has been run. It just doesn't say it outright, which is a shame.

Comment: I think he means which of these sums gives the value of total.

Comment: Compute some values by hand. If some (or all..) of the alternatives differ, you can shorten the list of your options.

Answer (score 1):

First lets look at the while loop to understand what our first iteration is. The while loop keeps looping until $i > n$. Now since $i = 1$ and it is doubled each time. This means your iteration of $i$ goes from $1$ to the amount of times you can divide $n$ by $2$ aka $\log_2 n$.

Now our second iteration $j$ is iterated from $1$ to $i$ each time adding $1$ to the sum therefore we have $\sum_{j=1}^i 1$.

Iterating this sum over all iterations of $i$ we get $$\sum_{i=1}^{log_2 n} \sum_{j=1}^i 1$$

So the answer is C, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

As far as your question is concerned, to analyze number of steps taken by your program try to find the following :

- *Number of values the iterator of outermost variable can assume.*

> **In your case** : *iterator* 'i' can assume values in set { 1, 2^1, 2^2, 2^3 ....., 2^k }, where 2^k is equal to n. So there are log<sub>2</sub>(n) values which 'i' can assume.

- *Number of values every other iterator can take, assuming certain value for iterators of all the loops enclosing the loop concerned with iterator under consideration.*

> **In your case** : *iterator* 'j' can assume values in set { 0 ....., ic-1 }, where 'ic' is certain value assumed for outer iterator 'i'. So, the contents inside this loop are executed 'ic' times for all possible values 'ic' which iterator 'i' can assume.

- *Evaluate total steps from above analysis.*

> **In your case** : Total steps is equal to { summ(ic=1,log<sub>2</sub>(n)) [ summ(jc=0,ic-1) [ 1 ] ] }, which is equivalent to you option c.

*If you wish to look further into how to analyse the number of steps involved in programs involving loops, check out these articles :*

[Article 1 : Analysis of Loops](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-of-algorithms-set-4-analysis-of-loops/)

[Article 2 : Loop Analysis when iterator grows/shrinks exponentially](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexity-loop-loop-variable-expands-shrinks-exponentially/)